# richfaces datatable row configuration

Tags: jsf, richfaces

I am using rich faces data table tag in my jsf:

```
<r:dataTable id="dataTable" var="user" preserveDataModel="false"

                value="#{ListUsersManagedBean.users}" rows="10"
                rowId="#{user.firstName}" rowKeyVar="index"

                width="500" style="float:centre" reRender="ds" columnClasses="center">
```

Here i have configured rowsize as 10 in static way.I want to give the user a dropdown in the table so he can select number of rows  100,200,300,400 etc below the column.How can i do this.Or any better solution?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do that by binding a variable to rows like `rows = #{yourBean.noOfRows}` and same to the combo box, and `reRender` your `datatable` onChange of `comboBox`.

This can be done if you are strict to use `<rich:dataTable>` or you can use jQuery [datatable](http://www.datatables.net/) easy to integrate and easy to use for the functionality you need.